# Azure Docker Container - how to pass startup commands to a docker run?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

Faced with this screen, I have managed to easily deploy a rails app to azure, on docker container app service, but logging it is a pain since the only way they have access to logs is through FTP.

[image]

Has anyone figured out a good way to running the docker run command inside azure so it essentially accepts any params.

in this case it's trying to simply log to a remote service, if anyone also has other suggestions of retrieving logs except FTP, would massively appreciate.

Comment: You can access logs using bash console via Kudu interface. While not the best way to process logs, it is lot better than FTP option IMO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, at the time of writing this is not possible, you can only pass in anything that you would normally pass to `docker run container:tag %YOUR_STARTUP_COMMAND_WILL_GO_HERE_AS_IS%`, so after your container name.

TLDR you cannot pass any startup parameters to Linux WebApp except for the command that needs to be run in the container. Lets say you want to run your container called `MYPYTHON` using the `PROD` tag and run some python code, you would do something like this

```
Startup Command = /usr/bin/python3 /home/code/my_python_entry_point.py
```

and that would get appended (AT THE VERY END ONLY) to the actual docker command:

```
docker run -t username/MYPYTHON:PROD /usr/bin/python3 /home/code/my_python_entry_point.py
```

Comment: So you mean, in that form after the image and tag name, is that correct?

Comment: yes, so essentially what to execute on container startup, updated answer @alexanderkustov

Comment: Only it does not allow me to pass the validation like this -  https://cldup.com/NMrI2UHuKM-3000x3000.png am i doing this right?

Comment: Sorry, still cant understand what you are saying... any other possible way of explaining it, maybe a visual example?